# Persistent error while using Xdebug trace

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to use the xdebug trace. I keep getting an error. I'd like to double check what error is with this code?

```
if (function_exists(xdebug_start_trace()))
{
    xdebug_start_trace();
}

include_once 'filename/bootstrap.php';

if (function_exists(xdebug_stop_trace() ) )
{
    xdebug_stop_trace();
}
```

Error message says:

> void function xdebug_start_trace result used

Not sure how to resolve unless I am being dumb and missing something obvious.

Comment: `function_exists` accepts function NAME, as a string. But you are passing actual function return value (which is `void` / "no value") there. RTM please: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php